# Converting textbox input to string

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript and am looking for some help. I am trying to make a JSON request based on textbox input. I want the text form the box to be a part of the request, however I cannot make the text be a string so that it can be used for the JSON request. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<p id="syno"></p>


<form name="test">
<input type="text"  name="Edit"> <!-- where i input a word-->
<input type="button" value="Test" onClick="gettext()"><!-- test button-->
<input type="text" name="Edit2" value="power" readonly style="border:1px solid white">
</form>


<script>
function gettext() {
document.test.Edit2.value = document.test.Edit.value;
document.test.Edit2("Edit2").value = document.test.Edit.value;
}


var apiKey = '0771a4c95ca7e23d41e33f67a1da0000/';
var txtjson = '/json';
var f = document.test.Edit2.value;
var apiUrl = 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/' + apiKey + f + txtjson;

$.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: parseWord
    });

function parseWord(data) {
           $('#syno').text(data.noun.syn);
         }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issues in code

1. you have added `ajax` code but code is outside of `gettext()` function
2. code line `document.test.Edit2("Edit2")` should be as `document.forms.test.Edit2.value`

see correct code,

```js
function gettext() {

  document.forms.test.Edit2.value = document.forms.test.Edit.value;
  var apiKey = '0771a4c95ca7e23d41e33f67a1da0000/';
  var txtjson = '/json';
  var f = document.forms.test.Edit2.value;
  var apiUrl = 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/' + apiKey + f + txtjson;

  $.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: parseWord
  });
  return false;
}




function parseWord(data) {
  $('#syno').text(data.noun.syn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="syno"></p>
<form name="test">
  <input type="text" name="Edit" />
  <!-- where i input a word-->
  <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="return gettext(this);" />
  <!-- test button-->
  <input type="text" name="Edit2" value="power" readonly style="border:1px solid white" />
</form>
```